# How to retrieve all valid 'ProductGroup's with Amazon Product Advertising API

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

I need to retrieve all the valid "ProductGroup"s an Amazon product can have to match it with my website categories. Unfortunately I haven't been able to retrieve this list both using the API or browsing the Amazon website as per the docs that state:

> You can find the complete list of product groups by going to www.amazon.com and clicking the tab that says "See All 32 Product Categories."

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/ItemLookup.html

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This page seems to have a list of all the available nodes

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/BrowseNodeIDs.html

Edit:
@bahmait points out to use this link http://www.browsenodes.com/node--2000.html
It does not seem official, but it does seems to be auto-generated by what you would get from the api.

I tried to search the same content from the link i posted above, but the closest i have now is http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodeIDValues.html

here is the nice content they had before (thanks internet archive!)

http://web.archive.org/web/20130109093331/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/BrowseNodeIDs.html

The bottom line: Their vendor api has zero categorization, just like their site.

Comment: Link out of date. Best I have been able to come up with recently is [this](http://www.browsenodes.com/node--2000.html), the look of which does not inspire confidence.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to "ProductGroup" is `BrowseNode`. I think that Amazon has stopped providing an updated list of top-level nodes.

Try something like the following:

Pick a SearchIndex from the the list they provide [in the doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/SearchIndices.html).

Do an `ItemSearch` with keywords that specify the kind of thing you're looking for, and that specify the `BrowseNodes` response group.

Parse the `BrowseNodes` you get back for `Ancestors`, per the [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/BrowseNodes.html), going back as far as you think you need to.

If you have a fixed list of products, and you have the the `ASIN` for each  product, then you can do an `ItemLookup` as above.